# MySQL transaction error_count

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm using MySQL version 5.1.60 and I have a script like the following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
USE myDB;
DELETE FROM mytbl WHERE .......
DELETE FROM mytbl2 WHERE ......
....
INSERT INTO mytblN VALUE (.......
UPDATE mytbl SET .....
....
COMMIT;
```

Now, if any statement fails for any reason the execution of the script stops, I get the error message and I have to issue manually a ROLLBACK; and fix the relevant statement.
This script contains from hundreds to thousands statements and if many fails it is hard to fix each statement one by one.

I'm looking for a way to get all the errors in one shot and to have the transaction to rollback automatically.

Somewhere I found that if I replace the final

```
COMMIT;
```

with the following

```
SELECT IF(@@error_count=0,'COMMIT;','ROLLBACK;') INTO @res;
PREPARE stmt FROM @res;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

and combine it with a

> --force

parameter executing the script from command line I would get what I wanted.

Unfortunately I found that the system variable @@error_count 'reset' after each statement, and also the MySQL documentation states it:

> error_count
>
> The number of errors that resulted from the last statement that
>   generated messages. This variable is read only. See Section 14.7.5.17,
>   “SHOW ERRORS Syntax”.

Is there a way, without using a Stored Procedure, to obtain what I want?
So when I call the script from command line like:

```
>mysql -u root -p --force < myscript.sql >log.txt 2>&1
```

I have all the error logged in the log.txt file and the transaction rolled back?

many thanks in advance.